# Group Woocommerce users by Coupon

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hopefully some legend can point me in the right direction.

I am wanting to group users who use certain coupon codes in woocommerce when they purchase. I realise there are plugins such as woocommerce groups which allow you to restrict coupons to user groups but I need this the other way.

Eg: someone uses a coupon code "cricket" when they purchase and this will then add the user to the group "cricket-users".

Thanks V much!

Comment: Do they need to become their own user role or would adding user meta be enough?

Comment: No they don’t need to add their own group. Group would be created beforehand and then once they purchase with a particular code it would then add them to that group automatically.

Comment: How are you creating the group?

Comment: Groups have just been creates using the User Role Editor in WP. Dan, you are a star!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'coupon_group', 10, 1);

function coupon_group( $order_id ){
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    foreach( $order->get_used_coupons() as $coupon_name ){

        // Retrieving the coupon ID
        $coupon_post_obj = get_page_by_title($coupon_name, OBJECT, 'shop_coupon');
        $coupon_id = $coupon_post_obj->ID;


        $coupons_obj = new WC_Coupon($coupon_id);

        if( $coupons_obj->is_type( 'cricket' ) ){

                //get the user id of the customer from the order
                $user_id = $order->get_user_id()
                /*
                *
                * logic that adds the user to the group cricket users
                * i.e. $add_user_to_coupon_group = add_user_meta($user_id, 'custom_user_group', 'cricket_users');
                *
                *
                */
        }


    }
}
```