# Woocommerce - set role of customer by coupon

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, roles, coupon

In woocommerce: I would like to group customers when they make their first order.
I installed "user role editor" plugin to create specific role (Example: student, teacher, ...)

At his first order/register, the customer **has** to complete the coupon field to register.
The coupon content is for example "student-coupon"

How to set **the role** of the customer depending of the coupon?

I tried this method:

[Group Woocommerce users by Coupon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835641/group-woocommerce-users-by-coupon)

... but i couldn't make it work...

Here is my code:

```
 // ASSIGN GROUP FROM COUPON

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'coupon_group', 10, 1);

function coupon_group( $order_id ){
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    foreach( $order->get_used_coupons() as $coupon_name ){

        // Retrieving the coupon ID
        $coupon_post_obj = get_page_by_title($coupon_name, OBJECT, 'shop_coupon');
        $coupon_id = $coupon_post_obj->ID;


        $coupons_obj = new WC_Coupon($coupon_id);

        if( $coupons_obj->is_type( 'student' ) ){

                //get the user id of the customer from the order
                $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
                /*
                *
                * logic that adds the user to the group cricket users
                * i.e. $add_user_to_coupon_group = add_user_meta($user_id, 'custom_user_group', 'cricket_users');
                *
                *
                */
                $add_user_to_coupon_group = add_user_meta($user_id, 'student', 'student_users');
        }


    }
}
```

The coupon title is "student".

The "User Role editor" role is Student (ID student).

... Not sure if i have to change both 'custom_user_group' AND 'cricket_users' or only 'cricket_users' on the "$add_user_to_coupon_group" line

maybe somebody see a better solution?

Thank's

Comment: I think the answer you have quoted is the better way to do what you want. edit your question to show the code you test.

Comment: *I tried this method... but i couldn't make it work* - then can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing what did not work?  The more detail you can share about your specific problem, the more likely we will be able to help. See: [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/.

Comment: Sorry about that... i edit post and give more details...